# ,Can anyone help me with upgrading ubuntu-mate 20.04 on my raspberry pi 4?

Tags: upgrade, error-handling

I got an upgrade notification to upgrade to 20.10. I tried with both the command terminal and the updater.

It starts to update but each time I get an error message. Tells me the problem is with the network connection. I have a wifi connection and I tried an Ethernet connection.

Each time I get the same error.
Can someone please help me with this?

Bellow is the error message I get every time I try to upgrade

E:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80], E:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1287576/edit) your question and mention the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can put that address in your browser to see that the source files do not exist on the internet, so it's not being maintained any more.

I have done a search for those files, and they seem to still exist at these locations, so you can try to replace the URLs in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with one of them:

```
http://18.219.209.11/ubuntu-ports/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/
http://52.15.97.248/ubuntu-ports/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/
http://212.47.225.68/ubuntu-ports/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/
http://91.189.94.8/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.10/prod/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/
```

If you don't want to bother with a text editor, from the command line:

```
sudo sed -i s@/us.archive.ubuntu.com@/91.189.94.8@g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If apt complains that they contain files that are not signed with the official keys, then your best course of action would be to create a new SD card from an updated image, and then just copy over your /home directory with an SD Card adapter.